# Add input text on enter to list, clear text. On click close class, remove parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, parent

I'm a beginner with javascript and jquery. I want the user to enter text into an input field, press enter, clear the field, and add the text to a list. In the list item there should be a link to remove it from the list.

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
  <li><input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter your text" /></li>
  <li>text<a href="#" class="close">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$("input").on("keydown",function search(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    var text = $('#text').val();
    if(text.length){
      $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.list');
    }
    event.currentTarget.value = "";
  }
});

$('.close').on('click', '.itemDelete', function() {
  $(this).closest('.li').remove();
});
```

link to plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lGemDbBsoklXCGASM8Qd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example. The trick is to use a `keyup` event handler and then make sure it was the enter key that was pressed (`13`). Then you can use jquery to append `li`'s to the `ul` In order to fulfill your requirement of removing the list item, are you basically saying to just remove the list item you clicked on?

**HTML**

```
    <input id="myInput" type="text" />
    <ul id="list">
        <li>text<a href="#" class="close">x</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#list').append($('<li />').append($('<a />', {href: '#', text: $('#myInput').val()}).click(function (e) {
            $(this).parent().remove();  
        })));
        $('#myInput').val('')
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, when you click on link with class close, it should close it's parent `li`.

Comment: The above code will work for you then. Please mark as answer if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to get this to work. If you want to overlook my code for critique, feel free.

**Javascript**

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var text = $('#myInput').val();
        var close = '<li>' + text + '<a href="#" class="close">x</a></li>';

        $('#list').append(close);
        $('#myInput').val('');
      }
});

$("#list").on( "click", ".close", function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lGemDbBsoklXCGASM8Qd